# Set theme effect for application in AppStore view

Tags: ios, app-store

Nowadays some of the application in App Store have some theme effect, like this:

[image: Sample screenshot]

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/quik-video-editor-by-gopro/id694164275?mt=8

How can I set the theme like this in my app?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, it is not possible to set the theme yourself.

If your app is popular and Apple think that you app worth having a custom page design, they will contact you.

You can also refer to this [link](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/113327#113327) of forums.developer.apple.com.

Comment: I agree with Leo. App refer by Vignesh is also Editor's choice.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Leo, There is no other way to customise my application page ?

Comment: I think there is no other way to do so.